Temperamental connection between RStudio and GitHub
I can download repositories through GitHub desktop onto my computer. The first time I open the R-project within the repository everything works fine, I can edit documents and commit/push as per normal. Once I close the R-project the connection between RStudio and GitHub appears to break, and when I re-open the R-project a second time the connection with Git no longer exists (the Git tab within RStudio is completely gone). If I delete the repository from my computer completely and re-clone it through GitHub desktop then the connection is established again and I can open the R-project, edit documents and commit/push as per normal.
Any advice or suggestions as to why this might be or how to resolve it would be appreciated?
I am at a loss as to where to start. I have tried re-installing both RStudio and Git Bash.
